# Disable tr with radio box using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".trHide input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
     });
 <tr>
      <td><ul type="circle">
          <li>9. Capacité à rendre compte</li>
        </ul></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" name="number9" value="1" <?php if($value['9.CapasityRendre'] == 1):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number9" type="radio" value="2" <?php if($value['9.CapasityRendre'] == 2):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number9" type="radio" value="3" <?php if($value['9.CapasityRendre'] == 3):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number9" type="radio" value="4" <?php if($value['9.CapasityRendre'] == 4):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number9" type="radio" value="5" <?php if($value['9.CapasityRendre'] == 5):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trHide">
      <td><ul type="circle">
          <li>10. Capacité à faire des choix et à prendre des décisions</li>
        </ul></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" name="number10" value="1"<?php if($value['10.CapaciteFair'] == 1):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number10" type="radio" value="2"<?php if($value['10.CapaciteFair'] == 2):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number10" type="radio" value="3"<?php if($value['10.CapaciteFair'] == 3):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number10" type="radio" value="4"<?php if($value['10.CapaciteFair'] == 4):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number10" type="radio" value="5"<?php if($value['10.CapaciteFair'] == 5):?>checked='checked'<?php endif; ?>></td>
    </tr>
```

**I need:**

I want to disable all the radio box in tag `<tr class="trHide">` .

**Problem:**

It dose not work.how would I fix this? Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: "It dose not work" doesn't explain very much. Post your code that doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't `console.log($(".trHide input:radio"))` output the desired elements?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/tTC9y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having disabled instead of true, like the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trHide input:radio").attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```